# User Interaction disabled in subview of a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am adding a set of views into a mainview as follows.i.e I have a view which contains a set of subviews (Label,Button etc).then this view added to the mainview. My ptoblem is when I tapped in the Button in the View its `IBAction` not invoked. My question is how invoke the Button tap action inside the subview of mainView?

```
for (int i = 0;i < controls.count;i++) {
         UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]init];
         view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            for (int j=0; j<viewsArray.count; j++) {

                  UIView *subView = viewsArray[i]; // this may be Button, Label etc
                  subView.tag = controlCount++;
             [view addSubview:subView];
            }
            [self.mainView addSubview:view];
        }
```

Comment: write this  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnObj];

Comment: Its didn't resolve the issue

Comment: have you set action on button?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the UIView (the variable `view`) frame isn't set (it's 0,0,0,0).

Change to:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:<a frame>];
```

where `<a frame>` could be `CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)` for example.

The subview of that view should also have it's frame set. Remember that the views (`subview`) frame refers to the frame in its parent view (in your case `view`)

You can remove `view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Comment: I have set the frame as you said but no luck :(

Comment: Set the frame of the subview as well. Try adding:
subView.frame = view.bounds; And make sure self.mainView's got a frame ofc.